# creation order of subnet with terraform

Tags: terraform

I need to create 6 subnets with below cidr value but it's order has been changed while creating it with terraform.

```
private_subnets = {
    "10.1.80.0/27"   = "x"
    "10.1.80.32/27" = "x"
    "10.1.80.64/28"   = "y"
    "10.1.80.80/28" = "y"
    "10.1.80.96/27"   = "z"
    "10.1.80.128/27"   = "z"
 }
```

Terraform is creating with 10.1.80.0/27 , 10.1.80.128/27,10.1.80.32/27,10.1.80.64/28,10.1.80.80/28,10.1.80.96/27 order

Module of terraform:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
    vpc_id            = "${var.vpc_id}"
    cidr_block        = "${element(keys(var.private_subnets), count.index)}"
    availability_zone = "${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}"
    count             = "${length(var.private_subnets)}"
    tags {
        Name         = "${lookup(var.private_subnets, element(keys(var.private_subnets), count.index))}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your `private_subnets` a map instead of a straight list? You don't appear to be using the x, y, z values at all here.

Comment: we are setting up the tags and some other computation on the basis of these names

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer:

Thanks to the discussion in the comments, I revise my answer:

You are assuming an order within a dictionary. This is not intended behaviour. As from your example, one can see that terraform orders the keys alphabetically internally, i.e., you can "think" of your variable as

```
private_subnets = {
    "10.1.80.0/27"   = "x"
    "10.1.80.128/27" = "z"
    "10.1.80.32/27"  = "x"
    "10.1.80.64/28"  = "y"
    "10.1.80.80/28"  = "y"
    "10.1.80.96/27"  = "z"
 }
```

You are running into problems, because you are having mismatches with your other variable `var.availability_zones` where you assume the index to be sorted the same as for `var.private_subnets`.

Relying on the above ordering (alphabetically), is not a good solution, since it may change with any version of terraform (order of keys is not guaranteed).

Hence, I propose to use a list of maps:

```
private_subnets = [
    {
        "cidr" = "10.1.80.0/27"
        "name" = "x"
        "availability_zone" = 1
    },
    {
        "cidr" = "10.1.80.32/27"
        "name" = "x"
        "availability_zone" = 2
    }, 
    …
]
```

I encoded the availability zone as index of your `var.availability_zones` list. However, you could also consider using the availability zone directly.

The adaption of your code is straightforward: Get (`element(…)`) the list element to get the map and then `lookup(…)` the desired key.

### Old Answer (not applicable here):

Before Terraform creates any resources, it creates a graphstructure to represent all the objects it wants to track (create, update, delete) and the dependencies upon one another.

In your example, 6 different `aws_subnet` objects are created in the graph which do not depend on each other (there is no variable in one subnet dependent on another subnet).

When Terraform now tries to create the attributes, it does so concurrently in (potentially) multiple threads and creates resources potentially simultaniously, if they do not depend on each other.
This is why you might see very different orders of execution within multiple runs of terraform.

Note that this is a feature, since if you have many resources to be created that have no dependency on each other, they all are created simultaneously saving a lot of time with long-running creation operations.

---

A solution to your problem is to explicitly model the dependencies you are thinking of. Why should one subnet be created before the other? And if so, how can you make them dependent (e.g. via `depends_on` parameter)?

Answering this questions should bring you into the right direction to model your code according to your required layout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's just sorting the map by some hash not anything else. It should be stable for the same keys.

Comment: There is no guarantee of an execution order. Multiple resources are created by multiple threads in general (you can observe that if you have a resource with a very long creation time, i.e. an `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster`). While it is being created, other resources are created in parallel.

Comment: While the algorithm to determine a [topological ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph might be fixed (and thus provide the same results for the same version), there is no guarantee to it.

Comment: Except it's looping through the map so it is ordered by the keys.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR During the creation of the graph, the loop does indeed take place. But when finding an order for execution, this looping order does not need to be respected.

Comment: The order of execution is irrelevant to the ordering of this though. The OP cares about the order only because it's linking subnets to availability zones different to what is expected because of the order of the loop. I doubt they care about which subnet is actually created first.

Comment: We need to map these subnets with availability zones and in my case, I think the mapping will help.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR You are right, I missunderstood the problem.